# C++ checking an int or char and returning a text

Tags: c++, converters, typeconverter

I was wondering if there was a specific function for checking if an input is an int or a character.

And then returning an answer, like "This is an integer" or "This is a character".

If there is not specific function for converting, how should I go about doing it?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: characters are integers. Also, one digit integers can be represented by a single `char`. You need to provide more detail.

Comment: You can use `std::isdigit()` for checking single characters of the input.

Comment: Do you need to do that in runtime? Because in compile time they can be distinguished using function overload or templates...

Answer (score 1):

Take the input as a string. Check if the string consists of a single character or multiple characters (digits only). However what would you consider '2' as ? The character 2 or an integer valued 2 ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use isdigit function to check whether the character entered is integer or not which checks for digit 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
like:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    char inp;
    cin>>inp;
    if(isdigit(inp))
        cout<<"Integer";
    else
        cout<<"Character";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did

```
#include<ctype.h>
str_int_check(char *a)//checks weather all elements of string are integers
{
    int flag= 0;
    for(int i = 0; a[i]; i++)
    {
        if(isdigit(a[i])) ;
        else if (a[i]== '-' && i == 0);//in case of negative values
        else
        {
            flag = -1;
            break;
        }
    }

    return flag;        //returns 0 if all characters are digit, else returns 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer trial-and-error approach: try to parse incoming string as integer, check for errors, if so, passed value wasn't integer. For example, [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol) have very convinient interface:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

#include <errno.h>

const char* the_answer(const char* str) {
    char* end; // Pointer to first invalid character found by strtol
    const char* endstr = str + std::strlen(str); // Last character in string

    long val = strtol(str, &end, 10);

    if(val == 0) {
        // Not all characters were parsed, consider as characters
        if(endstr != end)
            return "This is an characters";

        // This is valid, but too long integer to be kept in long type
        if(errno == ERANGE) 
            return "This is an integer";
    }

    return "This is an integer";
}
```

Which gives this:

```
0 This is an integer
20 This is an integer
-20 This is an integer
2000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 This is an integer
0xABCD This is an characters
Hello, World This is an characters
```

P.S. returning strings from `the_answer` is actually joke, return enumerated values or boolean.